# Delphi SHGetFolderPath and null terminated string

Tags: delphi

I am using this function to get user folder:

```
function LocalAppDataPath : string;
const
  SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
var
  path: array [0..MaxChar] of char;
begin
  SHGetFolderPath(0,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,0,SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,@path[0]);
  Result := StrPas(path);
end;
```

It is working great.
But after I add this lib to my project: **OpenJpeg** 
The returned values from this function is: C. It seems like for some reason each char in the "path" array has #0 after it and for this reason the returned string it truncated right at the start.

When I remove: **OpenJpeg** from my uses it all works good.

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: SHGetFolderPath is deprecated you can try Unicode and ANSI names
 `SHGetFolderPathW()` (**Unicode**) and `SHGetFolderPathA()` (**ANSI**). Also we can't see your delphi version.

Comment: @moskito-x: `ShGetFolderPath` maps to either the W or the A version, depending on the version of Delphi, i.e. whether it is "Unicode" or not. It is not deprecated. But apparently, OpenJPeg messes things up with its own import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the very top of the `OpenJpeg` unit is found this code:

```
type
  Char = AnsiChar;
```

This unit is therefore toxic when used in a Unicode Delphi. When you use `Char` in your code you are expecting a `WideChar` but this evil type alias confounds you.

My advice is to modify the library to remove that type alias and replace every use of `Char` with `AnsiChar`.

If you don't want to do that you can fully qualify `Char` as `System.Char`, or use `WideChar` explicitly in your code. However, this unit is, as I said, toxic, and it really needs to be remedied.

If you enable the [Typed-Checked Pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_(Delphi)) compiler option, the compiler will stop you from passing a `PAnsiChar` to a function expecting a `PWideChar`, and vice versa, when using the `@` address operator. Better to find your mistakes at compile time if possible.

You can simplify the code by passing `path` in place of `@path[0]`.

Please don't use `StrPas`. It has long been deprecated. You can simply write

```
Result := path;
```

The array is one character longer than necessary. That is, assuming `MaxChar` is what I think it is. Anyway, the array should be

```
path: array [0..MAX_PATH-1] of char;
```

You also fail to perform any error checking on the API call. Please check for errors as described in the documentation.

Comment: You don't need the `@` address operator to begin with.  Replace `@path[0]` with just `path`, the compiler will still detect any type mismatch error.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer which is a totally logical explanation of the problem. But, for some reason it still doesn't work. I changed the function to be: ShlObj.SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @path);. The "@" before the "path" is still needed and the returned array still has the #0 issue.

Comment: You enabled type checked pointers? Perhaps what actually happened is that `char` got redefined. Remember that you can see this other unit and we cannot. Did you look at it?

Comment: The fact that you need @ tells me that there's a type mismatch. The compiler will tell you that. But you don't tell us that error message, which you then suppress. When the compiler tells you that your types don't match, you should take heed.

Comment: Yes OpenJpeg redefines Char in a hopeless manner. The person who wrote that library is somewhat clueless. I urge you to heed every piece of advice in my answer.